# htaccess redrict some page to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to make some url rewrite

```
http://www.domain.com/products/feed.php?keywords=*somewords*
```

=>

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/products/feed/*somewords*
```

I have set in htaccess

```
RewriteRule 301 products/feed.php?keywords=(.*?) http://subdomain.domain.com/products/feed/$2.xml
```

but it seens not working, how to make a right write? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain].com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(products/feed)\.php\?keywords=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.domain.com/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]
```

You will also need this rule in subdomain's root's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(products/feed)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php?keywords=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Not the same subdomain ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} keywords=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^products/feed\.php$ http://subdomain.domain.com/products/feed/%1 [NC,NE,L,R=301]
```